# how to properly authenticate user with devise_token_auth rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, token

I am trying to write a simple test for a URL which should be visible only to logged in user (I use before_action `:authenticate_user!` to achieve this).

Even though I (think) that I properly assign all the headers I always get JSON response `{"errors":["Authorized users only."]}`

My test looks like this (Login (to get header info) then visit protected URL with all the headers needed)

```
post "/api/v1/auth/sign_in", {:email => user.email, password: 'password'}

header_hash = {
    'access-token'  => response.headers['access-token'],
    'uid'           => response.headers['uid'],
    'client'        => response.headers['client'],
    'expiry'        => response.headers['expiry']
}

get "/api/v1/subscription_status", nil , header_hash
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know that authentication token is changing on each request by default.

conf/device_token_auth.rb

```
config.change_headers_on_each_request = false
```

I set this setting to false and afterwards I got responses which I expected.